# How to push data (currentTime and duration of a song) to redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am making an audio player.
This is my `audio` tag:

```
        <audio
          ref={audioReference}
          src={currentSong.audio}
          onTimeUpdate={timeUpdateHandler}>
        </audio>
```

and here is the `timeUpdateHandler`:

```
  const timeUpdateHandler = (e) => {
    const current = e.target.currentTime;
    const duration = e.target.duration;
  };
```

Here, `current` contains the current time as the song plays and `duration` contains the duration of the song that is playing.
I want to push these two variables to the redux state so that I can show them on the screen.

This is my redux state in another file:

```
const initState = {
  allSongs: songData(),
  currentSong: { ...songData()[0] },
  isPlaying: false,
  isLibraryOpen: false,
  currentTime: 0,
  duration: 0,
};
```

This is the action type and action creator:

```
const PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE = "timerUpdate";

export const timerUpdate = () => {
  return {
    type: PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE,
  };
};
```

How should the action type and the reducer function look like and how will the payload work here? I am new to this so it is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your action could contains that time information

```js
const PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE = "timerUpdate";

export const timerUpdate = (current, duration) => {
  return {
    type: PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE,
    payload: {time: current, duration } 
  };
};
```

Then you can have as many reducers you want to calculate the state. Let say `isPlaying` reducer will return true when action is PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE. Similar currentTime and duration can be 2 different reducers.

Here is one approach, you might need to check [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

*reducers.js*

```
const isPlaying = (state=false, action) => {
  if(action.type=== PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE) return true;
  // implement the stop
  return state
},

const currentTime = (state=0, action) =>{
  if(action.type=== PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE) return action.payload.time;
  return state
}

const duration = (state=0, action) =>{
  if(action.type=== PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE) return action.payload.duration;
  return state
}

export default combineReducers({
 isPlaying,
 currentTime,
 duration,
})
```